# Data Acquisition

Tags: microcontroller, data-acquisition

I need to acquire some analog signals and read a digital signal at fixed sampling frequency.
What is the correct way for do this?

Note that this is not trivial because during the acquisition process, at given sampling time, the digital signal can missing due the fast sampling rate respect to the digital signal frequency. 
For example think at digital square wave of 50Hz frequency and a sampling rate of 100Hz.

Comment: this is not a stackoverflow question, there is an electrical stackexchange site that you can ask, but it wont fit there either as this is asking for recommendations and that is not what these sites are about.  there are countless ways to do this and you need to start looking around.  there are many DAC solutions going up to scopes with storage.  all depends on sample rate, number of bits duration, quality, etc.

Comment: THEN if you get something and your code isnt working and you can post a minimal example with your expectations and actual results, all the details about the hardware you bought, THEN that is a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I understand,what you mean. I'm sorry for the wrong question in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a suitable data acquisition system. For example [Dewes oft data acquisition systems](https://dewesoft.com/products) are really easy to use and have highly flexible software that requires zero programming to acquire, store and analyse the data.

They offer interface to any analog signal and sensor and also offer digital data buses like CAN bus, CAN FD, XCP, EtherCAT, EtherNET, video, and others.